# How to find window size (from a website) through javascript in a function, then hide/show elements depending on the size?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I've been trying to find many solutions to this, and while I have found many examples that show how to hide/show elements, and how to adjust the css of the website, I simply cannot get something to disappear. (Forgot to add, it is the button for the sidebar) I am trying to create a sidebar, that when the width of the window is less than 1000px, it appears on the left side of the screen (in the header section). If it is larger then it should not be there. The only solution I've managed to work was adding !important after a @media query. However, I have seen that this is not the optimal solution. I've gone through tons of material but I simply cannot understand or find the solution. I have a minimum understanding of javascript coding, so it's been rather difficult to say the least.

```js
function hidebutton() {
  var width = window.innerWidth;

  if (width > 1000) {
    document.getElementById("main").style.display = "none";
  }
}
```

```css
.openbtn {
  font-size: 25px;
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  color: #000;
  border: none;
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<div id="main">
  <button class="openbtn" onclick="openNav()" onload="hidebutton()"></button>
</div>
```

Comment: Please post the code snippet of where you can show, whats the problem ?

Comment: share the code here . you can use the snippet button `[<>]` to dispatch html/css/js . then it can be run to demonstrate your issue. screenshot of codes won'nt help you to get help.

Comment: I'm having issues with the function in the java script, the third image. It's not working, and I'm not sure if that is the way to do it.

Comment: your code should be run on load and resize, use @media (CSS mediaquerie ) instead which is made for this kind of things.

Comment: you also have it in javascript : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/matchMedia .... but again to be run onload and refresh on onresize . that is not optimal to my point of vue nowdays.

Comment: Sorry I'm not that familiar with stack overflow and I'm having issues with adding in the code

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251361/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks explains how to add code with proper formatting.

Answer (score 0):

You can Get this from Window Object`var w = window.innerWidth; var h = window.innerHeight;`

Answer (score 0):

Try out this JavaScript code:

```js
window.addEventListener("resize", function() {
    if (window.innerWidth > 1000) {
        document.getElementById("main").style.display = "none";
    }
    else {
        document.getElementById("main").style.display = "block";
    }
});
```

It is not optimal to use it, I would suggest using CSS `@media`, but if you want to do it with JavaScript, you can do it like that.

EDIT: I didn't see that you wanted to make the menu button disappear, try setting the id in the script to the id of your button.

Comment: you could use https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/matchMedia  in your script ;)

Comment: This might seem stupid to ask, but how would that be integrated to a function to call it via html?

Comment: Thank you, this did seem to work for the most part. Although it only disappears once the browser ration had been adjusted.

Comment: here is the example i thought of : `let mql = window.matchMedia("(max-width: 1000px)"); //* reset here your querie */
let el = document.querySelector("#main");
window.addEventListener("resize", function () {
  if (mql.matches == true) {
    el.style.display = "none";
  } else {
    el.style.display = "block";
  }
});` It was only to talk about mediaquerie which are via CSS or javaScript reliable today. CSS seems to me optimal because already built-in while javaScript comes as an extra scripting ;)